# Comparing double-precision numbers that are potentially infinite

Tags: java, double, equality, infinity

I have two double variables that can potentially be equal to Infinity. I would like to compare them and allow for a margin of error. I cannot use assertEquals due to the environment I work with.

I tried

```
assert Math.abs(a-b)<DELTA;
```

But if both a and b are Infinity this returns false. Is there a short way to check for equality without making an explicit check for the Infinity case?

Comment: What asserting/unit-testing framework do you use? Most of them have an `assertEquals` variant that takes a delta.

Comment: Why not `assert a == b || Math.abs(a-b) < DELTA;`?

Comment: How do you want to deal with NaN?

Comment: @user207421 this is probably the best option. I was hoping for something like Double.compareWithMargin but I guess there is no such built in functionality. Thanks!

Comment: No need to guess whether it exists. Just look up the Javadoc for `Double`.

Comment: @user207421 I've promoted your comment to an answer, as that is effectively what it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70140649/1108305

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution for this.  Your simplest solution would be to do one check which covers the infinity equality check, and another to handle the delta comparison.  The following is probably about the simplest way of doing this that handles both positive and negative infinity:

```java
assert a == b || Math.abs(a-b) < DELTA;
```

Comment: Solution provided by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632372/comparing-double-precision-numbers-that-are-potentially-infinite/70140649#comment119543906_67632372) by @user207421.